# Ruby - how to add phonecall's length? CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have class `Call` - it represents single phonecall with certain number of minutes/seconds, date of the call etc. I want to sum length of calls for given day.
Problem is my data is in string format, I'm formatting it with various `Time.parse` options and many different things. 
But my main problem is, how to sum them? I need something like Ruby's `inject`/`reduce` but smart enough to know 60 seconds is one minute.
One additional problem is I'm reading from .CSV file, turning every row into Hash, and making Call objects out of it.
Any hints? :)

Comment: Do you consider just storing the number seconds as an integer in the database? So instead of storing `"1:43"` store `103`. That makes it much easier to calculate (sum or average) with the values.

Comment: Yep, I'd generalize it as "if it's possible to do math on values, always store them as numbers. If math is impossible, store them as strings or other appropriate types" This makes call duration a number, but, say, house street number a string. Yes, it __looks__ like a number at first (even the name says "number"), but a) you can't do math and b) this structure will break the second you'll have to store an address like "Baker Street 221b"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I like your rule of thumb. I would like to add the suggestion to always store such values normalizes in [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).

Comment: Problem is I'm reading from .CSV file, turning every row into Hash, and making objects out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to store the duration of a call as a number of second in an integer. Because that would allow you to easily run calculation in the database.

But if you prefer to keep the string representation you might want to use something like this:

```
# assuming `calls` is an array of call instances and the 
# duration of the call is stores an attribute `duration`
total = calls.sum do |call|
  minutes, seconds = call.duration.split(':')
  minutes * 60 + seconds
end

# format output
"#{total / 60}:#{total % 60}"
```

Please note that the `sum` method is part of ActiveSupport. When you are using pure Ruby without Rails you need to use this instead:

```
total = calls.inject(0) do |sum, call|
  minutes, seconds = call.duration.split(':')
  sum + minutes * 60 + seconds
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint - I'm getting error "undefined method sum for Array"

Answer (score 0):

You may could `map` them all to seconds represented by `Float` via `Time.parse`, then `inject` the mapped float array.

Comment: but would it know to convert 60 seconds to one minute?

Comment: Because you would write a piece of code that multiplies the number of minutes by 60?